# Are mode and theme imports required for react-ace?

Tags: ace-editor, react-ace

I am using [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) for my project.

According to the document, if I want to use mode and theme, two import statements are needed.

```
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-java";
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github';

 <AceEditor
    mode="java"
    theme="github"
    onChange={onChange}
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
  />,
```

However, seems like the mode and the theme of editor can be set only passing props to the `AceEditor` component without declaring those `import` statements.

Can any issue be introduced if I omit those statments?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to omit the `import` statements the ace-editor will try to fetch them dynamically from your local host and you will get console errors.

You must also include '*ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace*', otherwise specific functionalities (like markers) won't work and you will see exceptions from *ace.js* library file.